# Is there a way to directly scan a QR code into a webpage via a webcam?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, web, barcode-scanner

I want to allow a user to be able to enter data in a webpage by simply scanning a QR code.

I'm not sure if there is something I can embed into the page / combined with some library to achieve this,  or if I need to look at using something external to the browser?

If its a solution that's platform specific, then I'm wanting something for windows mainly.  But ideally it would work across PCs and tablets.

Comment: You could do this with Silverlight. Here is a nice resource describing how SilverLight and javascript can interact together: http://pietschsoft.com/post/2008/06/19/Silverlight-and-JavaScript-Interop-Basics.aspx. The HTML5 spec has a webcam API in the works that could handle this once it's released across most browsers. [Chrome webcam API](http://www.webrtc.org/running-the-demos)

Comment: yeah, I just found this, https://github.com/LazarSoft/jsqrcode   which uses HTML5 to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there's no uniform webcam handling for javascript, but there is for flash, albeit the user has to grant access first.

Typing *qr code flash* into my browser brought up this webpage: http://miniqr.com/reader.php/

Or try to search for *qr code actionscript* - you need a reader library.

Comment: actually, after I posted that I found http://www.webqr.com/index.html  which uses HTML5 to get at the webcam

Comment: but the code isn't open source, and it seems to use a port of Zxing which I'm trying to find

Comment: It is also flash-based :) At least in my firefox it is. It's using this lib: http://www.taboca.com/p/camcanvas/

Comment: FWIW, it's got a bit of ZXing in it, but in a lot of significant ways, it's very different. I only mention it because from a quick glance at the code, I wouldn't expect it to decode as well as the Java or C++ ports of ZXing. There is an actionscript port of ZXing in the main ZXing repo, but it's not maintained very actively.

Answer (score 0):

Web code runs on a web server. Javascript runs on the client. Unfortunately, you can't control a client's webcam through Javascript (imagine the security and privacy issues we'd have if you could). This leaves you with three options.

1) HTML5. HTML5 has new standards that will allow you to control a webcam. Unfortunately, HTML5 is still new and I believe Google Chrome and Opera are the only browsers that have webcam access to date.

2) Silverlight. Starting with Silverlight 4, you can now access a user's webcam. Silverlight is a good way to do it and easy, however its not as wide spread as our final option:

3) Adobe Flash. Using flash you can access a user's webcam and the good news is that flash is very wide spread and almost all computers will be able to run your code.

So these are your choices. Pick one! Good Luck!